# How can I get the amound of seconds from a NSDate ("hh:mm:ss") and vice versa

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, countdown, countdowntimer

I am trying to make a timer and yes I have looked at NSTimer and it is not what I'm looking for, I basically need a way to convert a NSDate in the format of ("hh:mm:ss") into the amount of seconds that would be in this. And then I need a way to do the opposite so convert the seconds to the amount of hours, minutes and leftover seconds from that.

Comment: Are you talking about converting a string into `NSDate` and converting an `NSDate` into a string?

Comment: Do you have an `NSDate` or do you have an `NSString` in the format `hh:mm:ss`?

Comment: @rmaddy My NSDate is in the format hh:mm:ss

Comment: @Freddy Im trying to convert it to an int from the seconds in NSDate

Comment: @JoshuaThirkell No you don't. An `NSDate` has no format. Perhaps you converted the `NSDate` to an `NSString` using an `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: If you have an NSDate and want the seconds you can use `NSDateComponents`. I'll submit an answer.

Comment: NSDateFormatter and thousands of examples on the web.

Comment: @rmaddy sorry I should have been more clear that is what I meant

Comment: @JoshuaThirkell FYI - you are getting so many down votes because your question is unclear, you have not shown what you actually have, what you clearly want, or any effort to find a solution yourself before posting. Some relevant code in your question (not in the comments) showing what you have and what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract components from `NSDate` using the `NSCalendar` class. The following example extracts a single component, `NSCalendarUnitSecond`, from the current date.

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *localCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSUInteger seconds = [localCalendar component:NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate:today];
```

Answer (score -2):

You could have a place holder date e.g. 00:00:00 and then use the NSDate function timeIntervalSinceDate: to get the seconds. Converting back again you could use the dateWithTimeInterval: method.

Obviously both these dates would have to be the same year month and day and you could use any arbitrary values for these as long as they are the same.